# How to slice and store a set of curves in multiple variables in matlab?

Tags: matlab, slice

I have a table with 2 columns (x and y value) and 100 rows (the x values repeat in a certain interval).

[image: Set of linear functions]

Therfore I would like to perform the following task for changeable table sizes (only changes in the row size!):

> I want to determine the amount of repetitions of the x values and save this information as a variable named n. Here the amount of repetition is 5 (each x value occurs 5 times in total).

> I want to know the range of the x values from repetition circle and save this information as R = height(range); Here the x range is [0,20]

With the above informaton I would like the create smaller tables where only one repetition of the x values is present

How could I implement this in matlab?

Stay safe and healthy,

Greta

Comment: Your question is unclear. `M` is a table or a matrice ? What do `M` contains ? The value of the variable of a straight line equation `a*x + b` ? Is `NUM == n` ? `R_x` should be automatically detected based on what ? Also, splitting your table/matrice into `n` variables is generally not a good idea since you won't be able to index your table/matrix anymore to retrieve the useful information. Why would you do that ?

Comment: Sorry wrong phrasing will edit question again

Comment: Store the `x` values in a set with [`unique`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.unique.html) and [reshape](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach converts the `Table` to an array/matrix using the `table2array()` function for further processing. To find the repeated pattern in the x-values the `unique()` function is used to retrieve the vector that is repeated multiple times. The range of the values can be calculated by using the `min()` and `max()` functions and concatenating the values in a 2 element array. The `assignin()` function can then be used to create a set of smaller tables that separate the y-values according to the x-value repetitions.

### Table Used to Test Script:

```
x = repmat((1:20).',[5 1]);
y = rand(100,1);
Table = array2table([x y]);
```

---

### Script:

```
Array = table2array(Table);
Unique_X_Values = unique(Array(:,1));

Number_Of_Repetitions = length(Array)/length(Unique_X_Values);

Range = [min(Array(:,1)) max(Array(:,1))];

Y_Reshaped = reshape(Array(:,2),[numel(Array(:,2))/Number_Of_Repetitions Number_Of_Repetitions]);

for Column_Index = 1: Number_Of_Repetitions
    Variable_Name = ['Small_Tables_' num2str(Column_Index)];
    assignin('base',Variable_Name,array2table(Y_Reshaped(:,Column_Index)));
    eval(Variable_Name);
end

fprintf("Number of repetitions: %d\n",Number_Of_Repetitions);
fprintf("Range: [%d,%d]\n",Range(1),Range(2));
```

Comment: @MichealTr7 Thank you for the detailed explenation. Tried this code out and it works. Thank you for your help again!

Comment: @MichealTr7 I have casted o vote for you. However I get a message that the vote was recorded but not publicly displayed due to a lack of reputation.